# The return type is incompatible with '@NonNull Page<M>' returned from PagingAndSortingRepository<M,String>.findAll(Pageable)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, non-nullable, pageable

Code:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AbstractRepository <M extends AbstractModel> extends MongoRepository<M, String> {
     Page<M> findAll(Pageable pageable);
     Page<M> findAllByIsActive(boolean isActive, Pageable pageable);
}
```

And are other warning in findAll parameter:

```
   Missing non-null annotation: inherited method from PagingAndSortingRepository<M,String> specifies this parameter as @NonNullJava(67109781)
```

whats wrong?